# Input values of multiple checkboxes selected to a single textbox vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple checkboxes and a single textbox. How can I have the value of all checkboxes ticked to that single textbox in VBA Userform?
My form looks like this..

[image]

Comment: where is your code attempt ?

Comment: @ShaiRado I'm still trying to figure it out.. I don't have any sample code yet.. :(

Comment: @Meedee Look at this site to help you going http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you so much for that link!!! I got it now! :)

Answer (score 2):

IIF for president:

```
Textbox1.Value=iif(chk1,"AccountBlaBla","") & iif(chk2,"Orders","") & _
iif(chk3,"ReturningBlaBla","")
```

etc. IIF is a nice inline IF alternative, you can use it in concatenations. If the value of checkbox1 is true, then add some text to the concatenation, etc. You might want to use a separate variable to assemble the text, might be easier on the eyes...

Comment: Thank you.. I haven't used IIF before, but I'll try to play with these codes, too..

Answer (score 0):

***Solution approach:***

This will give you the function to get the values of the thicked boxes, since it's a function, use it as needed

***Code:***

```
Option Base 1
Function Array_Ticked_Checkboxes() As String()
Dim ItemControl As Control
Dim DummyArray() As String
Dim CounterDummy As Long
    For Each ItemControl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ItemControl) = "CheckBox" Then ' 1. If TypeName(ItemControl) = "CheckBox"
    'you can't do both checkings at the same time because it will give error on items that are not checkboxes
    If ItemControl.Value = True Then CounterDummy = CounterDummy + 1: ReDim Preserve DummyArray(CounterDummy): DummyArray(CounterDummy) = ItemControl.Caption
    End If ' 1. If TypeName(ItemControl) = "CheckBox"
    Next ItemControl
    Array_Ticked_Checkboxes = DummyArray
End Function
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ArrayTickedCheckboxes() As String
Dim ItemArray As Variant
    ArrayTickedCheckboxes = Array_Ticked_Checkboxes
    On Error GoTo Err01CommandButton1_Click
    For Each ItemArray In ArrayTickedCheckboxes
    MsgBox ItemArray
    Next ItemArray
Err01CommandButton1_Click:
End Sub
```

***Sample:***
[image]

Comment: If the answer is helpful/suits your needs don't forget to click useful/accepted answer accordingly :)